# split-window: command not found. How to reassign / remap tmux keys to split window?

Tags: tmux

For a long time I've used tmux for split horizontal and vertical windows

I found the default key mappings cumbersome and so I remapped split vertical and split horizontal from being the quotes (`"`) and percentage (`%`) keys to being the `-` and `|` keys.

I remapped these to "|" and "-" which I find both easier to remember and easier to key (less hand stretching!)

However with the latest version of tmux this mapping is not longer recognized.
I get errors about `split-window: command not found`

I can still use the original keys - " and % - without a problem

This is the mapping I've used previously:

```
bind | split-window -h -c '#{pane_current_path}'  # Split panes horizontal
bind - split-window -v -c '#{pane_current_path}'  # Split panes vertically
```

More Details:

```
tmux source ~/.tmuux.conf
```

gives

```
$ tmux source ~/.tmux.conf
tmux source ~/.tmux.conf
unknown key:  split-window
history -a
```

Update: using quotes around the mapping key works.

Comment: Are the keybindings listed if you run list-keys? I'm using: bind "'" split-window -h and:
bind "-" split-window -v, which works fine.

Comment: I don't see them as mappings  When I do your command I get "split-window: command not found".  Maybe my tmux version?

Comment: I am using tmux 3.0a and i recently upgraded Ubuntu from 19 to 20 (current version).

Comment: This is odd, because the split-window command has not been changed in recent versions. Is it possible for you to test on another instance/version of tmux? I'm also using tmux 3.0a (which is not the latest btw).

Comment: bash version 5.0.17(1)

Comment: Same. And it's in your .tmux.conf which has been reloaded?

Comment: See more details for output

Comment: Please post your entire .tmux.conf. Thanks.

Comment: will do.  one sec: i have found one thing that works: `bind | split` lets me bind the shift-`\` key (i.e. the `|` key.  However it doesn't let me bind the unshifted `\` key - I get `readline; split: no key sequence terminator`.  Not surprising given it is the backslash key.  I tried escaping and double escaping it but no luck

Comment: Let's get your basic keybindings to work first, then move on to exotic characters second. :-)

Comment: Here it is. thanks for helping me https://gist.github.com/durrantm/56a5b4ed00b5ab0b75aed4b4f79ccb17

Comment: I would recommend putting any special characters in quotes. Does it work if you comment out line 13 and add a new line with: `bind - split-window -v`

Comment: If you want to use backslash I suggest: `bind '\' split-window -h `

Comment: Hi Artur I tried all these suggestion (and several varieties of them) and they all give errors of either `unknown key: split-window` or `no key sequence terminator`.  I checked anotehr computer that uses this tmux conf file and worked fine before and it has the same issues.  However I also recently upgraded that from Ubuntu 19 to 20, possibly creating the same issues (if the upgrade is related).

Comment: correction - your solution of using quotes around the key DOES work

Comment: please post as answer

Comment: Thanks - and good luck!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

After reviewing your .tmux.conf it would appear that the error is binding the \ key without quotes. The correct binding would then be:

```
bind '\' split-window -h
```

The same goes if you want to use the quote keys, in which case you would have to use either:

```
bind '"' split-window -h
```

or

```
bind "'" split-window -h
```

Next, you could try adding the second parameter `-c '#{pane_current_path}'` and see if it still works.